# Homomorphic image of a Sylow p-subgroup is Sylow p-subgroup.

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory

Let $G$ be finite group and $\phi$ : $G \to H$ be a group epimorphism. If $P$ is a Sylow p-subgroup of $G$ then $\phi(P)$ is a Sylow p-subgroup of $H$.

It looks very simple but I'm stuck here.

Let $\lvert P\rvert=p^{k}$. Clearly $\lvert \phi(P)\rvert=p^{n}$ where $n\leq k$. Suppose $\phi(P)$ is not a maximal p-subgroup in $H$ and let $Q$ be a maximal p-subgroup of $H$ containing $\phi(P)$. Then $\lvert Q\rvert=p^{m}$ where $n<m$ and $\phi^{-1}(Q)$ is strictly larger than $P$.

For the rest of the proof, what can I do? Thanks.

Comment: $[H:\phi(P)]=[G:\phi^{-1}(\phi(P))]$ has no prime factor $p$ since $P\subseteq\phi^{-1}(\phi(P))$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hint: by one of the isomorphism theorems $H = \phi(G) \cong G/ker(\phi)$. Write $N=ker(\phi)$. The image of $P$ under $\phi$ is $PN/N$. And this latter group $\cong P/P \cap N$. Can you show from here that $PN/N \in Syl_p(G/N)$?

Comment: Yes! the index of $PN/N$ in $G/N$ is equal to the index of $PK$ in $G$ because of the correspondence between the coset spaces. Since $P$ is a Sylow p-subgroup of in $G$, the index of $PN$ is prime to $p$, and so is the index of $PN/N$ in $G/N$. But I didn't use the fact that $P/(P \cap N) \backsimeq PN/N$. Thanks!

Comment: Ergin well done!

Comment: @ErginSuer, the fact that the index of $PN/N$ in $G/N$ is prime to $p$ may not be sufficient, because in that case we can only have $|PN/N|=p^m q$, where $p$ is a prime and $p$ and $q$ are relatively prime. I think we still need to apply $P/(P\cap N)\cong PN/N$, so that we can show that $|PN/N|$ is a power of $p$, only in this way are we done. Is that right?

Comment: Yes correct. In general, the order of a homomorphic image of a group $X$, divides $|X|$.